# Polymer Bower Components Paper Card Not Working

Tags: html, polymer, material-design, paper-elements

Trying to get to grips with Polymer and the whole Material Design side of things. I have used this at work and it runs correctly, however when I am attempting to do things on my own at home it never works properly... Even if I am installing the examples from Polymer themselves, ie:

```
polymer init polymer-1-application
```

For example in the title I have given the paper-card component which just doesn't seem to work. I have gotten the app-header/app-toolbar up and running but that was by copying and pasting other code in.

Please see code below (I am only going to include the important bits and pieces, please assume all of the tags are correct)

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="elements/newProj-header-bar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/newProj-card.html">

  <style>/* CSS HERE */</style>
</head>
<body unresolved>

  <newProj-header-bar></newProj-header-bar>
  <newProj-card></newProj-card>

</body>
</html>
```

### new-Poj-header-bar.html (all code included)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">

<dom-module id="newProj-header-bar">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        background: #115f9b;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>

       <app-header slot="header" reveals shadow effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>Adam's App</div>
            <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="create"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'newProj-header-bar',

      properties: {

      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

### newProj-card.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">

<dom-module id="newProj-card">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
       <paper-card heading="Emmental" image="http://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
          <div class="card-content">
            Emmentaler or Emmental is a yellow, medium-hard cheese that originated in the area around Emmental, Switzerland. It is one of the cheeses of Switzerland, and is sometimes known as Swiss cheese.
          </div>
          <div class="card-actions">
            <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
            <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
          </div>
        </paper-card>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'newProj-card',

      properties: {

      },

    });
  </script>
```

### EDIT (14/06/17)

---

I changed the naming conventions to not have any capital letters as Pascal L suggested, however things still aren't working. I even tried with using paper-material, but no dice.

I will now show you the bower.json for paper-card to see if it something to do with incompatible versions or something...

***Looking for my bower.json file I found that I have a "bower.json" but also a ".bower.json" along with the standard ".gitignore" file... the dotted one seems to have a bit more info, but not sure what is going on or why two files...***

### paper-card/bower.json

```
{
  "name": "paper-card",
  "private": false,
  "main": "paper-card.html",
  "ignore": [
    "README.md"
    ],
  "dependencies": {
    "paper-shadow": "Polymer/paper-shadow#master",
    "paper-ripple": "Polymer/paper-ripple#master"
  }
}
```

### .bower.json

```
{
  "name": "paper-card",
  "private": false,
  "main": "paper-card.html",
  "ignore": [
    "README.md"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "paper-shadow": "Polymer/paper-shadow#master",
    "paper-ripple": "Polymer/paper-ripple#master"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/andytuwm/paper-card",
  "version": "0.1.5",
  "_release": "0.1.5",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "0.1.5",
    "commit": "092df7a4e6766a6acc26d42447811fcf2a844998"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/andytuwm/paper-card.git",
  "_target": "^0.1.5",
  "_originalSource": "paper-card",
  "_direct": true
}
```

Comment: what is your version of Polymer? (just type Polymer.version into console on your website.)Another thing is that I have no idea why you have `#master` affix in bower.json. I am using latest updates and for example, in my `bower.json` file i have most of the elements described like: `"paper-material": "PolymerElements/paper-material#^2.0.0",` It might have something to do with this. Try re-install every element using in your project.

Comment: Hey Kuba,Yes I think that I have somewhat sorted this now... It was to do with the versioning of the components. I had been using "bower install paper-card" to install the component but this would get the very earliest version for some reason. I then used "bower install Polymer/paper-card" which got the latest version and it now works.

Comment: yep, you should always follow instructions described in documentation on webcomponents.org. It's nice to know that `bower install paper-card` command shouldn't be use

Comment: Hey come on, it's what they told me to use and what I've used at work haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you must rename your newProj-card Component to new-proj-card since Html does not allow uppercase letters as tag names.

Comment: Hey Pascal, I changed my naming conventions however things still aren't working. Just wondering if it may be something to to with the versions of the paper components being incompatible with the version of Polymer I am running.

Comment: Well this could actually also be true i had this issue this week too i updated my bower dependencies and i got in my case paper-drawer for Polymer 2 but actually i still use polymer 1 which made my drawer stop working

Comment: Hey Pascal, Yeah I know what you mean. I accidentally updates Polymer the other day so now I only have 2 :-( Is there any way that you can import all of the latest stuff for bower components? I know there is the whole "bower install Polymer/polymer" command but that doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

Comment: Hi you can make bower get you the correct versions. Go to your bower.json and add a specific version to you polymer dependency for instance #>=1.9.1 <2.0.0 this would force it to stay on latest polymer version but not 2.0.0 and then do bower install -f which will re download all but with the version behind polymer it will only load dependencies that will fit to this restraint. [Doku for bower install](https://bower.io/docs/api/#install)